# Where can I find information about how to cite a web address using MLA?

Tags: citations, mla

Say I was trying to cite this question and properly format my works cited section using MLA.  Where would I look to find information on how to format it?

Comment: Are you asking for how to format a citation in the MLA style for a web address?

Comment: @Mitch yes please.

Comment: Oh. Did you try a web search already?

Comment: A [Google search for "MLA web citation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=MLA+web+citation) produces the exact link Kate posted as the very first result. But I suppose waiting a full day for someone else to google it for you makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

The OWL at Purdue is my go-to source for MLA information.  Check their page for [electronic sources](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/08/), or their [home page](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/).

Comment: I up voted your answer. I also wrote out a long form version of an answer, using a different source. Since it was current MLA, it provided similar content to the excellent URL you provided.

Answer (score 2):

I paraphrased this from Robert Harris' **[MLA In-Text Citation Style](http://www.virtualsalt.com/MLA-InText.html)**, November 2010. It is based on the Seventh Edition of MLA for Research Writers, 2009, which remains the most current version. Harris distinguishes between a web page and a database. Here is the standard for a web page, or web address, as the question requested.

> Last name, First name. “Article Title.” *Web site name*. Sponsoring
>   organization name, Date of article. Web. Date you accessed article.

Include as much of the information that you can find for the website. If you don't have the date, use `n.d.` for `no date` as follows:

> Last name, first name. “Article title.” *Web site*. Sponsoring
>   Organization, `n.d.` Web. Date you accessed article.

If you don't have the author's name, nor the date of the article:

> “Article title.” *Web site*. Sponsoring Organization, `n.d.` Web. Date you accessed article.

If the web site name is the same as the organization name, or no organization name is specified:

> Last name, first name. "Article title." *Site name*, Date of article.
>   Web. Date you accessed the article.

If the URL might be difficult to locate, include it in  brackets at the end of the citation:

> Last name, First name. “Article Title.” *Web Site*. Sponsoring
>   Organization, Date of article. Web. Date you accessed article.
>   `<http://xxxxxx.xxx/....>`.

Use **exactly** the same period and comma placements above for your citation.